# WCF How to change the Cryptographic Provider for an X.509 Certificate's Private Key

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, tpm

I am trying to extend WCF by following this [how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/change-cryptographic-provider-x509-certificate-private-key) guide from microsoft. The basic idea is to use  a hardware security module as the client-side private key holder, which means all cryptographic operations involving the client's private key must be carried out by the security module chip.

**Setup**

```
dotnet framework: 4.7.2
binding: netTcp
binding security: Message
clientCredentialType: Certificate (X509Certificate2) 
serverCertificate: X509Certificate2
```

All certificates ( 1 server cert and 2 client certs ) are signed off by the same CA. The server certificate is a normal `pfx` file that contains both the certificate and private key. I prepared two different client certificates one with the private key and one without the private key. (two client side `pfx` files have the identical certificate )

**Observations**:

1. When using the client `pfx` file **contains** the private key, the client is able to communicate to the server in the mtls fashion.
2. When using the client `pfx` file without the private key, the attempt to set up secure session fails with the following exception

```
System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
The certificate '<cert name>' must have a private key. The process must have access rights for the private key.
```

Stack Trace

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsSspiNegotiation.ValidatePrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsSspiNegotiation..ctor(String destination, Boolean isServer, SchProtocols protocolFlags, X509Certificate2 serverCertificate, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, Boolean clientCertRequired)
System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsnegoTokenProvider.CreateTlsSspiState(X509SecurityToken token)
System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsnegoTokenProvider.CreateNegotiationState(EndpointAddress target, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
```

3. In **neither** case, the provided `CustomX509AsymmetricSecurityKey` as per the how-to above was **NOT** used by the `WCF` framework. Did not even instantiate the class. The `CustomX509SecurityToken` was instantiated via the `CustomX509SecurityTokenProvider`. But the `SecurityKeys` property of the `CustomX509SecurityToken` class was never called, which is where the custom private key comes to play.

**Questions**

1. Is the [how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/change-cryptographic-provider-x509-certificate-private-key) guide out of date? Notice it is dated `03/30/2017`.
2. The exception when using the `pfx` without private key is sort of self-explanatory. I did not provide the private key. Why didn't WCF use the provided `CustomX509AsymmetricSecurityKey` as the private key? Isnt this the whole point that the user is providing an alternative private key in the form of a `X509AsymmetricSecurityKey`?
3. Am I following the wrong guide to achieve what I want? I did try to set the [`PrivateKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the `X509Certificate2` class with a custom [`RSA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netframework-4.7.2) implementation. But got lost trying to implement the [`ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface which is required by the `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`

Comment: Your current problem is that the settings in the document do not work for you, right?

Comment: I am trying to find a correct way to plugin a custom private key to WCF. Following the how-to did not get me there.

Comment: Have you successfully applied the configuration to the service? You can refer to this link, which includes applying custom client credentials to the service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/walkthrough-creating-custom-client-and-service-credentials

Comment: Thx. I think the custom client credentials on the SERVER side may not be the problem. The custom private key is on the client side.

Comment: did you check this reference may be helpful. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190290/should-the-client-or-the-server-generate-the-clients-public-private-key-pair